# Merge Sorting Alphabetically, worked with predetermined names earlier but not with command line files

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, toarray

so I'm trying to write a program that sorts the contents of a file typed in from the command line alphabetically. I'm having troubles with reading in the file and then copying it from an arrayList "myArrayList" to an array "myList" to be printed in my "main" here's my code:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.io.File ;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.Scanner ;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException ;

public class MergeSortLines {
public static void main(String[] args)
   throws FileNotFoundException {
    loadArray(args[0]) ;
}

public static String[] loadArray(String fileName)
   throws FileNotFoundException {
  String[] myList = null ;
  ArrayList<String> myArrayList = new ArrayList<String>();
  if ( (fileName != null) && (!fileName.equals("")) ) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(new File(fileName)) ;
    while (input.hasNextLine()) {
        String a = input.nextLine();
        myArrayList.add(a);
    }
    myList = myArrayList.toArray(new String[] {});
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(myList));

  }
 return myList ;
}


public static void mergeSort(String[] a) {
    if (a.length >= 2) {
        String[] left = new String[a.length / 2];
        String[] right = new String[a.length-a.length / 2];

        for (int i = 0; i < left.length; i++)
        {
            left[i] = a[i];
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < right.length; i++)
        {
            right[i] = a[i + a.length / 2];
        }

        mergeSort(left);
        mergeSort(right);

        merge(a, left, right);
    }
}

public static void merge(String[] result, String[] left, String[] right) {
    int i1 = 0;
    int i2 = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
        if (i2 >= right.length || (i1 < left.length &&
                             left[i1].compareToIgnoreCase(right[i2])<0)) {
                  result[i] = left[i1];
                  i1++;
             } else {
                  result[i] = right[i2];
                  i2++;
             }
        }
    }
}
```

it compiles correctly but I get a NoSuchElementException error code when I run it. My questions are, did I do the while loop correctly for the scanner? How do I utilize toArray() correctly? and finally, if I have the wrong idea, what is the correct way to copy the file to an array? Thanks I appreciate any help whatsoever!
**EDIT**
Thanks to HoverCraft Full of Eels, I got the contents of the file displaying properly, now it won't sort alphabetically when it worked with names I put in the code from when I started testing it! any ideas?

Comment: I'm not sure if this is contributing to your problem but as a general rule, your `Scanner#hasNextXXX()` should always be matched by a `Scanner#nextXXX()` of the same type. So if you state `while (input.hasNextLine())`, this should be followed by a single `input.nextLine()`.

Comment: Your three lines beginning with `myList = ` makes no sense. Why try to assign it three different objects when only the last call matters?? Also, which line is throwing your exception?

Comment: Ohhh thanks! It printed the file this time but it wasn't alphabetical how it was when I tested it, any ideas why this might be?

Comment: This line, `myList = new String[myArrayList.size()];` is still completely unnecessary and useless.

Comment: I got rid of it and compiled and ran and it told me it was a NullPointerException error so I gotta keep it

Comment: no, all you need is `myList = myArrayList.toArray(new String[]{});`

Comment: well okie dokie it works, however it still doesn't solve the problem of the contents of the file being alphabetized, any ideas there?

Comment: How is it magically going to be sorted? Where do you call any sorting code?

Comment: I have merge() and mergeSort(), in terms of calling where should they go?

Comment: That's just it -- where do you call mergeSort? You don't. You must at least try to sort something since again, nothing works by magic in programming -- if you want a method to do its work, the method must be called. I'd experiment and try to find a place where it works.

Comment: When I tested earlier without using the command line and just had     String[] list = {"Ryan", "Kelly", "Kyle", "Alex", "Riley"};
And it sorted just fine. Why does it work like that but doesn't work when I type it in from the command line?

Comment: Op nevermind I got it thanks you helped me a lot once again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer my own question, I neglected to call the methods to execute them so that the mergeSort would sort my list properly